# Shape key setting so that value slider doesn't work

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I have an object that when I make a shape key it doesn't go back to 'basis" when I tab out to object mode. The slider has no effect. I can change it between basis and the key only by selecting basis or the key.

I added a default cube and keys worked fine. I then compared for anything I could think of and nothing stands out. I've applied transformations (and not). It's not parented, no delta transforms, no constraints or axis locks on transformation.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Mark

[image: Added image for clarification]

Answer (score 1):

If the slider is greyed out, it could be that you have accidentally pushed this pin icon:

[image]

Comment: A brief explanation of why this pin is there and why it makes sense, that the slider is greyed out would be great.

Comment: My question is about a slider that "doesn't work" and "has no effect." It isn't greyed out. My apologies if I was too vague.  I've added a gif for clarification.